# how to change these codes to c# style?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

This is my HttpService class, it works fine. But it seems weird, the code in every function much the same. And I should write try/catch in every functions, espcially TaskCanceledException, if I do not catch it here, my application will terminate. Could some one give me some example about how to optimize the code?

```
[Export(typeof(IDataSource))]
public class HttpService : IDataSource
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public HttpService()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:3721");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public void Initialize(CurrentUser currentUser)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(currentUser.Name + ":" + currentUser.Password)));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> getUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/User");
            //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error code.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<User>>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<permission>> getPermission()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/User");
            //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error code.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<permission>>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public async Task<CurrentUser> getCurrentUserInfo(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/User?name=" + user.Name);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CurrentUser>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: The functions only differ by return type and by async method called. I think you could refactor this to be more reusable. Also, var result = x; next line return result; - don't do this, just return the result.

Comment: If you don't do anything specific on exceptions, catch the base Exception only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm not in a position to compile this so you may have to massage it some.

The only thing I see you could do is make a method like this:

```
public async Task<T> getAsync(string url)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
            return (T)result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then you could call it like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> getUsers()
{
    return await getAsync("api/User");
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<permission>> getPermission()
{
    return await getAsync("api/User");
}

public async Task<CurrentUser> getCurrentUserInfo(User user)
{
    return await getAsync("api/User?name=" + user.Name);
}
```

Comment: using the ternary operator in the body of `getAsync` might be more idiomatic as well.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I mean, c# style.

Comment: @T_T, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 5):

> if I do not catch it here, my application will terminate.

no, that is simply not true; it is the code that *invokes* it also has the chance (and indeed, responsibility) to handle the errors. For example:

```
try {
    var permission = await getPermission();
    //...
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // log, whatever
}
```

Putting the exception handling in the most appropriate place will reduce this unnecessary code in your `async` methods. What you are *currently* doing is making your `async` methods pretend that nothing bad happened - that is not the best practice here.

Comment: +1: You always have to be the voice of reason don't you! :D

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud a radical approach, but sometimes it works :)

Comment: Yes,it is simply true. I should check my codes again.